# socket.recv() receives less bytes than expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, file-sharing

This code downloads most of the file but not all of the file (inside a while loop) any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```py
data = csocket.recv(1024)
with open(filename, 'wb') as file_to_save:
    while data:
      file_to_save.write(data)
      time.sleep(.008)
      data = csocket.recv(1024)
      if len(data) < 1024:
         break
```

This code downloads roughly 600 bytes short when downloading 38,616 bytes size file.

Comment: Obvious answer, looks like len(data) < 1024 is being hit??

Comment: Sorry missed the declaration of 'data', edited the code look now.

Comment: How much of it is missing exactly...?

Comment: If I download a file with the size 38,616 bytes it is roughly 600 bytes short. (38,008 bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the recv() function does not guarantee to return the total amount of bytes you "request". The argument is just a maximum amount of bytes that you expect to receive, but the function can return less bytes than this if they are available in the buffer. Here it is an implementation from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

```
    def myreceive(self):
        chunks = []
        bytes_recd = 0
        while bytes_recd < MSGLEN:
            chunk = self.sock.recv(min(MSGLEN - bytes_recd, 2048))
            if chunk == b'':
                raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
            chunks.append(chunk)
            bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
        return b''.join(chunks)
```

As you can see the function repeats the recv() until the expected amount of bytes arrives. After each chunk arrives, the new recv() quests as maximum amount of bytes `MSGLEN – bytes_recd`. The min() is used to limit the amount for received bytes for each block to 2048. When the recv() function returns 0 bytes (chunk == b''), it means that the other side closed the connection.

For your case the `len(data)`  can a will return sometimes return less than 1024. your break condition should be `if len(data) < 1:`

Comment: when using if len(data) < 1: the code runs infinitely assuming in a infinite loop.

Comment: If the other side didn't close the connection, you will never receive zero bytes and your code will wait forever in the recv(1024). You need to find an other break condition for your loop. This is offen the case in stream connections, you can use a special character to mark the end of the transmission (it shouldn't aper in the message body), you could also finish after receiving X bytes (send first the package length) or implement your own protocol. 
The title of your question is misleading, maybe you could use something like "socket.recv() receives less bytes than expected"

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: I implemented what you suggested "you can use a special character to mark the end of the transmission" And the file receives more bytes than intended, does this mean the file is corrupted?

Comment: Not necessarily. This can be an encoding problem, or you are sending more than you think (for example you start sending a second file) or you are not counting the amount of expected characters correctly. If your end of transmission mark has more than one byte, check the byte order (little or big endian). As your original question was answered pleas mark ti as answered. If you have more questions, please ask a new one.